# Can't initialize static structure with function pointer from another translation unit?

Tags: c, c99, c89

The Python documentation claims that the following does not work on "some platforms or compilers":

```
int foo(int);  // Defined in another translation unit.
struct X { int (*fptr)(int); } x = {&foo};
```

Specifically, the Python docs say:

> We’d like to just assign this to the tp_new slot, but we can’t, for
>   portability sake, On some platforms or compilers, we can’t statically
>   initialize a structure member with a function defined in another C
>   module, so, instead, we’ll assign the tp_new slot in the module
>   initialization function just before calling PyType_Ready(). --http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html

Is the above standard C89 and/or C99?  What compilers specifically cannot handle the above?

Comment: There is no C compiler which can't handle it (any such compiler is not a C compiler), but as Dietrich pointed out, it may incur additional runtime cost (relocation) and may prevent the structure from being stored in a read-only segment even if it's declared `const`.

Comment: @R. but those things would be true as well for whatever might happen in the 'initialization function'.  So there's no potential additional harm done by using static initialization, right?

Comment: @Michael: Indeed. I think Python's documentation is just bogus on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to n1570 6.6 paragraph 9, the address of a function is an *address constant,* according to 6.7.9 this means that it can be used to initialize global variables.  I am almost certain this is also valid C89.

**However,**

On sane platforms, the value of a function pointer (or any pointer, other than `NULL`) is only known at runtime.  This means that the initialization of your structure can't take place until runtime.  This doesn't always apply to executables but it almost always applies to shared objects such as Python extensions.  I recommend reading Ulrich Drepper's essay on the subject ([link](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)).

I am not aware of which platforms this is broken on, but if the Python developers mention it, it's almost certainly because one of them got bitten by it.  If you're really curious, try looking at an old Python extension and seeing if there's an appropriate message in the commit logs.

**Edit:** It looks like most Python modules just do the normal thing and initialize type structures statically, e.g., `static type obj = { function_ptr ... };`.  For example, look at the `mmap` module, which is loaded dynamically.

Comment: N1570 is the latest (?) draft of the upcoming C201x standard.  It has no official status (yet), and nobody implements the language it describes.  [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), the newest C99 draft (incorporating the standard plus the three Technical Corrigenda) is more useful for most purposes.

Comment: @Keith: I was just referring to whatever was most convenient at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

That kind of initialization has been permitted since at least C90.

From C90 6.5.7 "Initialization"

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration or in an initializer list for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be constant expressions.

And 6.4 "Constant expressions":

> An address constant is a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly, using the unary & operator...

But it's certainly possible that some implementations might have trouble with the construct - I'd guess that wouldn't be true for modern implementations.

Comment: @Adam: my copy of the standard does have a section 6.4.  It's the "ANSI/ISO 9899-1990" standard. My understanding is that the numbering of sections changed from when ANSI first published the standard to when it became an ISO standard as well. Or something like that (so the numbering doesn't match what might be in the final draft ANSI C89 ASCII text document that's available on the Internet).

Answer (score 1):

The example is definitively conforming to C99, and AFAIR also C89.

If some particular (oldish) compiler has a problem with it, I don't think that the proposed solution is the way to go. Don't impose dynamic initialization to platforms that behave well. Instead, special case the weirdos that need special treatment. And try to phase them out as quickly as you may.